# Problem with Fullscreen Resolution in Mono Game

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fullscreen, resolution, monogame

a couple days ago I started game developing in MonoGame with Visual Studio 2017 and porting my code which i wrote in WinForms to MonoGame. Now I have a problem with the fullscreen mode. I searched the internet and the only thing I found out is that it depends on the resolution the monitor has.

In the default window mode of the application the screen looks like follows:

[image]

Now when I switch to fullscreen mode - this happens:

[image]

Now my problems are:

1. One can not see it on the picture because I used the print button and pasted in to paint but the image is largely strechted.
2. The right part of the screen is cut off
3. the sprites are moved to the top.

I'm using
`graphics.ToggleFullScreen();`

Is there a way to keep the original status like it is in window mode? Maybe to put flexible bars for a 4:3 mode and keep the sprite positions? My positions are fixed. So use something like
`spriteBatch.Draw(Params.CUR_SPRITE_P1, new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(POSITION_P1.X), Convert.ToInt32(POSITION_P1.Y), 750, 476), Color.White);` for the player position and the screen (to implement scrolling).

Or maybe adjust everything in full screen mode bu keep the positions of the sprites on different screen resolutions...

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Ok after searching and searching I finally found an answer:

```
var scaleX = (float)ActualWidth / VirtualWidth;
var scaleY = (float)ActualHeight / VirtualHeight;
var matrix = Matrix.CreateScale(scaleX, scaleY, 1.0f);

spriteBatch.Begin(transformMatrix: matrix);
```

This has to be put in the Draw()-Method.
My virtual screensize was 800x480. I tested it with my Monitor size 1920x1080 and this did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Every game/application made with MonoGame, if you intend to share it with a wider audience, should support multiple resolutions.  This in effect causes you to re-think how you might want to position a smaller game view-port inside a visible screen.  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillarbox ) - or if you want to try and scale your graphics, which could cause them to appear blurry / smudged.  There are lots of options!  So please consider reading a tutorial or two, such as this:

https://www.industrian.net/tutorials/changing-display-resolution/